# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE' in view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can someone please confirm how to get rid of the following error.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)
SELECT        
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID,
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre,
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Product_ID, 

dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounted_Amount AS Amount, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Account_Name, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date, 

dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Opex Type], 
dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Logistic_Solutions_Type

FROM            
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail 
INNER JOIN dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$ 
ON dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID = 
    dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Account Code] 
INNER JOIN dbo.LogSolOpexCC 
ON dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre = dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Cost_Centre

GROUP BY dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Product_ID, 

dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounted_Amount, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Account_Name, 
dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date, 

dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Opex Type],     
dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Logistic_Solutions_Type

HAVING (dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Comment: What's the database? Sybase, PostgreSQL, H2, Oracle, etc.

Comment: First, tag your database.  Second, no database I know of supports `@declare` in a view, only `SELECT` statements.

Comment: You can use : https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Comment: Manage to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass parameters to SQL Server views. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5147/limitations-when-working-with-sql-server-views/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Product_ID, 
                         dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounted_Amount AS Amount, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Account_Name, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date, 
                         dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Opex Type], dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Logistic_Solutions_Type
FROM            dbo.General_Ledger_Detail INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$ ON dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID = dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Account Code] INNER JOIN
                         dbo.LogSolOpexCC ON dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre = dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Cost_Centre
GROUP BY dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_ID, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Cost_Centre, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Product_ID, 
                         dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounted_Amount, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Account_Name, dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date, 
                         dbo.Account_Codes_Sales_OPEX$.[Opex Type], dbo.LogSolOpexCC.Logistic_Solutions_Type
HAVING        (dbo.General_Ledger_Detail.Accounting_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE()))
```